# How to upgrade Supermicro BIOS from WinPE (Norton Ghost shell)?

Tags: bios, norton-ghost, windows-pe, supermicro

I need to upgrade the BIOS on a Supermicro X6DAL-G/TG/XG/XTG system that runs Linux.  It has no floppy drive, so I need to upgrade from CD or USB key.

I've tried booting Norton Ghost 14.0 and using the command prompt.  I believe this is [WinPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment).  I then tried running AMIFLASH.COM from another CD, but Windows complains about not finding AMIFLASH.COM.  I can view README files in that same directory though.

Is there an issue with the PATH when booting from WinPE and swapping CDs?

EDIT: The exact error is:

> .\AMIFLASH.COM 6dal1997.rom /a /b /c
>   The system cannot find the file D:\6DAL1197\AMIFLASH.COM

Of course, `AMIFLASH.COM` exists in that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinPE probably doesn't have Virtual DOS Machine needed to run DOS mode COM files.  You need a MS-DOS boot disk.  If you have a Windows system you can use format to create an boot disk.